# Why is scrapy splash returning me the original url?

Tags: scrapy, rendering, scrapy-splash

It took a while but I finally understand where the discrepancies are coming from!

scrapy crawl MeetupGetParticipants with url https://www.meetup.com/Google-Cloud_Meetup_Singapore_by_Cloud-Ace/events/264513425/attendees/

```
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x04E0BD30>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://meetup.com/Google-Cloud_Meetup_Singapore_by_Cloud-Ace/events/264513425/attendees/ via http://localhost:8050/render.html>
[s]   response   <200 http://meetup.com/Google-Cloud_Meetup_Singapore_by_Cloud-Ace/events/264513425/attendees/>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x04E0BC70>
[s]   spider     <MeetupGetParticipants 'MeetupGetParticipants' at 0x4ff0450>
```

Why is Splash returning the original url? Isn't the purpose of Splash to return the one rendered by render.html? What I want is the result of http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www.meetup.com/Google-Cloud_Meetup_Singapore_by_Cloud-Ace/events/264513425/attendees/ (which gives me a rendered webpage).

Bascically i could make it work by myself just tricking the url ... There is something I don't understand here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I could make it work with a nice lua script :) It returns a rendered json response with everything I need in it.

```
def start_requests(self):
        lua_script = """
        function main(splash)
            assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
            while not splash:select('.attendee-item') do
                splash:wait(0.1)
            end
            return {html=splash:html()}
        end
        """

        yield SplashRequest(url=self.url, callback=self.parse,
                            endpoint='execute',
                            args={'lua_source': lua_script,
                                  'wait': 5,
                                  },
                            )
```